# comparing two maps and adding key to one map in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two maps named maps1 and list1, and how do I compare their object and if the object is same, the key for maps1 goes for list1's key in javascript.

I know that to add values in map, the code is written

```
map1[anykey] = value;
```

If map1 contains `{hi , hello}, {a, b}, {c, d}`
and list1 contains `[hi, a]`, I want to finally make a map2 that resembles something like this: `{hi, hello}, {a, b}`. is this anyway possible?

Comment: When you say "map" above, I'm guessing you mean "object." Similarly, when you say "list" above, I'm guessing you mean "array." (Note that as of ES2015, JavaScript has a `Map` type, so best to be specific about what you're using.)

Comment: *"If map1 contains `{hi , hello}, {a, b}, {c, d}`"* - That isn't really a valid JS object format. Did you mean `[{hi : "hello"}, {a : "b"}, {c : "d"}]` (that is, `maps1` is an array of objects), or...?

Comment: sorry for confusing explanation, what @nnnnnn is saying is what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new, blank <s>map</s> object, loop through the <s>list</s> array, and copy over any properties whose names are in it:

```
// Create the blank object
var newObject = Object.create(null); // Or just {} if you prefer

// Loop through the array
list.forEach(function(name) {
    // Does the original object have a property by this name?
    if (name in originalObject) {
        // Yes, copy its value over
        newObject[name] = originalObject[name];
    }
});
```